# Scraping pre-market table on Barchart with Python

Tags: python, ajax, web-scraping

Apologies if this is a bit website specific (barchart.com).  I used the guidance provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62605088/scraping-a-table-on-barchart-website-using-python?noredirect=1&lq=1) for properly connecting and scraping barchart.com for Futures data.  However, after hours of trying, I am at a loss as to how to pull off this same trick for their pre-market data table: [Barchart_Premarket_Site](https://www.barchart.com/stocks/pre-market-trading/volume-advances?orderBy=preMarketVolume&orderDir=desc).

Anyone know the trick to get the pre-market data?

Here is the basic connection, for which i get a 403:

```
import requests

geturl=r'https://www.barchart.com/stocks/pre-market-trading/volume-advances?orderBy=preMarketVolume&orderDir=desc'

s=requests.Session()
r=s.get(geturl)

#j=r.json()
print(r)`
```

Comment: You can not just make a request to a results page and expect the data to be returned in JSON format. As expected you get a 403 Forbidden error, because you are not allowed to access the data from this endpoint outside of the website. You will have to use an official API (that usually comes with an authentication token) from the source. Alternatively you can use python packages such as [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) which you can use to scrape the data from the site. However, please make sure to read the terms and conditions of the site to ensure you are allowed to scrape the data.

Comment: barcharts.com uses an API that requires cookies. This is the [sample code I made on Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1pbQDrW-YeTo38_27SggYYQGpZcU4c68q?usp=sharing) in order to try to answer this question, but, I'm unable to set correctly the session/cookies for get the JSON results - [JSON response](https://anotepad.com/notes/4rrx7tcp).

Comment: Following my comment, I used the code provided in the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62605088/12511801) and folowing the correction indicated in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62655887/12511801), the data can be obtained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that was required was to add more headers to the request.  You can find your own headers using chrome > developer tools; and then just find the api request for the table and slam in a few of the headers associated with that request.

```
import requests


request_url = "https://www.barchart.com/proxies/core-api/v1/quotes/get?lists=stocks.us.premarket.volume_advances&orderDir=desc&fields=symbol%2CsymbolName%2CpreMarketLastPrice%2CpreMarketPriceChange%2CpreMarketPercentChange%2CpreMarketVolume%2CpreMarketAverage5dVolume%2CpreMarketPreviousLast%2CpreMarketPreviousChange%2CpreMarketPreviousPercentChange%2CpreMarketTradeTime%2CnextEarningsDate%2CnextEarningsDate%2CtimeCode%2CsymbolCode%2CsymbolType%2ChasOptions&orderBy=preMarketVolume&meta=field.shortName%2Cfield.type%2Cfield.description%2Clists.lastUpdate&hasOptions=true&page=1&limit=100&raw=1"

headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'cookie': '_gcl_au=1.1.685644914.1670446600; _fbp=fb.1.1670446600221.1987872306; _pbjs_userid_consent_data=3524755945110770; _pubcid=e7cf9178-59bc-4a82-b6c4-a2708ed78b8d; _admrla=2.2-1e3aed0d7d9d2975-a678aeef-7671-11ed-803e-d12e87d011f0; _lr_env_src_ats=false; _cc_id=6c9e21e7f9c269f8501e2616f9e68632; __browsiUID=c0174d21-a0ab-4dfe-8978-29ae08f44964; __qca=P0-531499020-1670446603686; __gads=ID=220b766bf87e15f9-22fa0316ded8001f:T=1670446598:S=ALNI_MaEWcBqESsJKLF0AwoIVvrKjpjZ_g; panoramaId_expiry=1673549551401; panoramaId=9aa5615403becfbc8adf14a3024816d53938b8cdbea6c8f5cabb60112755d70c; udmsrc=%7B%7D; _pk_id.1.73a4=1aee00a1c66e897b.1672997455.; _ccm_inf=1; bcPremierAdsListScreen=true; _hjSessionUser_2563157=eyJpZCI6ImI2MTM5NTQ4LWUxYzMtNTU2NS04MmM3LTk4ODQ5MWNjY2YxZCIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOjE2NzMwMzQ3OTY0NDAsImV4aXN0aW5nIjp0cnVlfQ==; bcFreeUserPageView=0; _gid=GA1.2.449489725.1673276404; _ga_4HQ9CY2XKK=GS1.1.1673303248.3.0.1673303248.0.0.0; _ga=GA1.2.606341620.1670446600; __aaxsc=2; aasd=5%7C1673314072749; webinar131WebinarClosed=true; _lr_geo_location_state=NC; _lr_geo_location=US; udm_edge_floater_fcap=%5B1673397095403%2C1673392312561%2C1673078162569%2C1673076955809%2C1673075752582%2C1673066137343%2C1673056514808%2C1673051706099%2C1673042087115%2C1673037276340%2C1672960427551%2C1672952009965%2C1672947201101%5D; pbjs-unifiedid=%7B%22TDID%22%3A%2219345091-e7fd-4323-baeb-4627c879c6ba%22%2C%22TDID_LOOKUP%22%3A%22TRUE%22%2C%22TDID_CREATED_AT%22%3A%222022-12-05T19%3A48%3A10%22%7D; __gpi=UID=000008c6d06e1e0d:T=1670446598:RT=1673433090:S=ALNI_MZS6mLx8CJg9iN6kzx4JeDFHPOMjg; market=eyJpdiI6InJvcVNudkprUjQ1bE0yWWQrSTlYY1E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoieUpabHpmSnJGSkIxc0o1enpyb1dLdENBSWp4UE5NYUZwUFg3OGs0TGJSL0dQWUNpTDU0a2hZbklOQTFNd09OVSIsIm1hYyI6IjBjMjJkNDExZjRhOTc2M2QwYWU3NGUyNmVlZTgyMzY2NWM2MjQyOTY2MjY2YmUxODI2Y2RkY2FlNzI3MjNkOTIifQ%3D%3D; _lr_retry_request=true; __browsiSessionID=c02dadca-6355-415f-aa80-926cccd94759&true&false&DEFAULT&us&desktop-4.11.12&false; IC_ViewCounter_www.barchart.com=2; cto_bundle=dxDlRl90VldIJTJGa0VaRzRIS0xnQmdQOXVWVlhybWJ3NDluY29PelBnM0prMkFxZkxyZWh4dkZNZG9LcyUyRjY1VWlIMWRldkRVRlJ5QW05dHlsQU1xN2VmbzlJOXZFSTNlcFRxUkRxYiUyRlp6Z3hhUHpBekdReU5idVV0WnkxVll0eGp5TyUyQlVzJTJCVDVoRkpWWlZ4R0hOSUl2YTVJVDhBJTNEJTNE; cto_bidid=51ixCl92dkhqbmVmdnlTZHVYS25nWTk2eDVMUnVRNjhEMUhxa3FlcmFzRHVNSERUQkd5cFZrM0QyQyUyRkVNNkV6S0ZHOUZPcTBTR2lBUjA5QUc5YU1ucW9GMFZBWHB4aU9sMlo3WHAlMkJYWjZmJTJGWkpsWSUzRA; _awl=2.1673451629.5-df997ba8dc13bee936d8d14a9771e587-6763652d75732d6561737431-0; laravel_token=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%3D; XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6Ik1PMGEvOGFkZ1p1ekpNcXIvZWZtcHc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiMVZYQ3NCV1hjcWREdG5uSDVqYXZVVy91U29USys1dkJJeFNZZG9QVGNRNDhmMTJIeitVV2NUV0xSUC9ZTThVM3FDQWZBcVdNclhqSkx4MG1NTGhadUNlNXRLMEdUc3RDcEVwNnJVYU9FNTBub2NKRWxlekxBZmZEVXNhZUlwWnoiLCJtYWMiOiIxYTI0N2E2OGMxMzRhNmFiYTliMzBlYTdjYWZlNzUwMDRlY2Q5YjI2YzY4OGZlMWIxYmM0YTE3YzZkMTdhMGM3In0%3D; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6InJIcmMxRWVacmtGc2tENS9zYUFFOVE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoibG1vQWh1d1dmaUNBZTV4dGdJbWhTVEoyMWVrblBFNTBycTBPai9ad2llcHRkd0hHUTI4ZS8rUFNFVm5LNEcvd1RXY1RwOHdVZHplNU92Vk9xUHZjYmMrUC9Cc3hJUkJNWE54OVR1UHFaTExpM1BRcWRSWEJ5Q3gvVVNzajdHZUoiLCJtYWMiOiI5NDVkOGU4NGM5Y2MwMThmMTgwMzQyOWQ1Yzc5MzU5ZGU2ZjkwMWRjYzBjZWJiZDFhMTQzODMzZmE2NWExMGQ3In0%3D',
    'referer': 'https://www.barchart.com/stocks/pre-market-trading/volume-advances?orderBy=preMarketVolume&orderDir=desc',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'x-xsrf-token': 'eyJpdiI6Im1LQVRpVEJONzZwMDRVQnhYK0I5SWc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiMkRIMnJBb1VDQmRscjNlajF1dVR2eWxRbGNJTGZCNWxMaWk3N0EzQWlyOWk0cXJBK2oyUVJ1N282R2VOVWh6WlhJcXdZdFplZmRqaFhPa203bi9HeFBxckJKeUVzVDRETHI5OHlxNDZnOEF5WVV5NXdNSWJiWk95UlFHRXQwN2siLCJtYWMiOiI1NTkyZjk2M2FlNTE0NDI0ODQ3YmE4ZjIyZDY1MzM2MTA3ZTY4NDA5NzA5YzViMjhiN2UwYTFhNTM1Y2ZkMjk5In0='
}

r = requests.get(request_url,headers=headers)
```